# Android: Best way to load views dynamically in Android 2.1

Tags: android, layout

I am developing an application in Android 2.1 which requires loading of views dyamically based on button click. Here is the rough layout of my Activity.

[image]

Say on Clicking button1, it should display imageview, and on clicking button2, it should show listview, for button3 - linearlayout of button and images, and so on. All the views should be loaded in the provided white space only.

The approach I thought to follow is "Inflating layouts".But on clicking another button, old inflated layout should be removed and new inflated layout should be visible.

Are there any better ways to achieve this?? If Inflating layouts is the only better way, how can I remove old inflated layout and load new inflated layout.

Comment: you can use predefine layout and set visibility according to requirement.

Comment: you mean to write all the views in a single layout and set visibility to required views?? Actually I have a lot of buttons and so are the views. Loading all the views but displaying only 1 view may slow down the android system.

Comment: Yes but if have lot of view then use Inflating layouts, and next time when you inflate layout then set visibility INVISIBLE for the already created layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a ViewFlipper to hold the three layouts and simply call `showNext()` or `setDisplayedChild()` to determine which layout is shown.

Comment: Of all the answers provided here, seems like ViewFlipper is the best solution for me, but is viewflipper supported for android 2.1 ?

Comment: According to the documentation, ViewFlipper has been available since API level 1, so yes it should be. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html

Answer (score 0):

Inflating is good when you have more complex layout than just one `ImageView` or so. In this case you should just create an ImageView dynamically and add it to "the white space" (it should be some ViewGroup (i. e. RelativeView)). In this case:

```
mRelativeView.removeAllViews();
ImageView newView = new ImageView(mContext);
newView.setImageResource(R.drawable.someImage);
mRelativeView.addView(newView);
```

When having more complex layout, do it with LayoutInflater (but remember inflating is very slow):

```
mRelativeView.removeAllViews();
View newView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.some_layout, null);
mRelativeView.addView(newView);
```

In above examples `mContext` can be current Activity for instance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to do something very similar to `TabHost`, try reading on `TabHost` here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html

And see the tutorial here:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

I think you'd better off using built-in components like this then implementing something similar on your own

Comment: I know about TabHost but i think a separate Activity is required to create for each tab right ? I just want to load some views in a simple way.

Comment: No, it's not, from the link above: "You can implement your tab content in one of two ways: use the tabs to swap Views within the same Activity, or use the tabs to change between entirely separate activities."